# Measuring compactness using GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, geometry

Is there a way to find the compactness (ratio of perimeter to area) of various groups of contiguous cells using GRASS functions?

If you imagine I want to find the compactness of the three land parcels shown in the below picture [image]

Perhaps there are some reporting functions I can use to find the area and perimeter of these parcels and then I can determine the ratio myself?

Comment: Maybe this can guide you, https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Find_largest_patch_in_raster_map, although I guess you're trying to keep it raster

Comment: It kind of helps thank you @ElioDiaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`v.to.db`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.to.db.html) for this (see also keyword index, under "[compactness](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/keywords.html#compactness)"). Beforehand you need to vectorize your raster map with [`r.to.vect`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.to.vect.html).